# Computation for finding the largest prime factor of 600851475143 is slow

Tags: haskell, programming-challenge, primes, time-limit-exceeded

I implemented the following for Project 3 in [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3):

```
--Problem 3. The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the
--largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

prime :: Integer -> Bool
prime x = prime' x (x `div` 2) where
          prime' _ 1 = True
          prime' x y = if x `mod` y == 0 then False
                       else prime' x (y - 1)

largestPrimeFactor :: Integer => Maybe Integer
largestPrimeFactor x = largestPrimeFactor' x (x `div` 2)                       
             where largestPrimeFactor' _ 1 = Nothing
                   largestPrimeFactor' x y = if x `mod` y == 0 && prime y then Just y
                                             else largestPrimeFactor' x (y - 1)
```

I was able to get `Just 29` per the introduction to this problem from Project Euler:

```
*Main> largestPrimeFactor 13195
Just 29
*Main> largestPrimeFactor 600851475143 -- running for (as of now) 15 hours!
```

My implementation succeeded for getting `29` from `13195`, but the computation for `600851475143` has been running for 15 hours so far.

Please review my implementation for correctness and idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: You sure this isn't an issue with large number? Like an overflow or something like that? Did you try some other primes?

Comment: According to [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Integer), `Integer` is an arbitrary precision length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm doesn't scale.  In [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48185/9357), I've outlined the three common strategies for finding the largest prime factor of a number, only one of which is reasonably efficient.  You've chosen Option 2 (testing largest candidates first, then check for primality).  However, you start at \$\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\$ rather than \$\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil\$, which is even less efficient, and furthermore it incorrectly produces `Nothing` whenever `n` is already prime.

Here's a Haskell implementation of Option 3 (testing smallest candidates first):

```
largestPrimeFactor :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
largestPrimeFactor n
  | n <= 1    = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just $ largestPrimeFactor' n (2 : [3, 5..])
  where
    largestPrimeFactor' n pseudoprimeCandidates@(c:cs)
      | c * c >= n = n
      | m == 0     = largestPrimeFactor' d pseudoprimeCandidates
      | otherwise  = largestPrimeFactor' n cs
      where
        (d, m) = divMod n c
```

Personally, I'd avoid contaminating the output with `Maybe`, since `Nothing` will only result from obviously illegal input anyway.

```
largestPrimeFactor :: Integer -> Integer
largestPrimeFactor n
  | n <= 1    = error "largestPrimeFactor n where n <= 1"
  | otherwise = largestPrimeFactor' n (2 : [3, 5..])
  where
    largestPrimeFactor' n pseudoprimeCandidates@(c:cs)
      | c * c >= n = n
      | m == 0     = largestPrimeFactor' d pseudoprimeCandidates
      | otherwise  = largestPrimeFactor' n cs
      where
        (d, m) = divMod n c
```

Comment: The largest prime factor can be as large as n/2. For example `19 * 2 = 38`. Note that `19 > sqrt(38)`. This would need to be taken into account if working down from sqrt(n).

Comment: @githubphagocyte But it works. The function factors out the 2 and produces 19.

Comment: Ah I see. So in that particular case it is slightly slower to start at sqrt(n) than to start at n/2, but in cases where the largest prime factor isn't n/2 it would be much faster to start at sqrt(n) because the range between sqrt(n) and n/2 is much bigger than the range less than sqrt(n)? I think I get it now.

Comment: @githubphagocyte As specified by `(2 : [3, 5..])`, it is testing factors in this sequence: 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, ….

Comment: @trichoplax: The number here is around 600 billion. It is not even, so n/2 (about 300 billion) is not a factor. Then all the numbers _between_ n/3 and n/2, that's about 100 billion, cannot possibly be factors of n! And after that, none of the numbers _between_ n/4 and n/3 (that is 50 billion numbers between 150 and 200 billion) cannot be factors of n.