# Project Euler #3 in Haskell

Tags: haskell, programming-challenge, primes

[Project Euler #3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) asks:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

I've written a general solution for any number:

```
module Main where

isDiv :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
n `isDiv` k = n `mod` k == 0

fullyDiv :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fullyDiv n k
    | n `isDiv` k = fullyDiv (n `div` k) k
    | otherwise = n

intSqrt :: Integer -> Integer
intSqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral

maxPrimeFact :: Integer -> Integer
maxPrimeFact n = go n (1, wheel)
    where
        wheel = 2 : [3,5..intSqrt n]
        go n (x, []) = if n == 1 then x else n
        go n (x, (y:ys))
            | n `isDiv` y =
                let o = fullyDiv n y
                in go o (y, takeWhile (<= intSqrt o) ys)
            | otherwise = go n (x, ys)

problem3 :: Integer -> Integer
problem3 = maxPrimeFact

main :: IO ()
main = do
    _ <- getLine
    contents <- getContents
    let cases = map read $ lines contents
    let results = map problem3 cases
    mapM_ print results
```

An explanation of this algorithm can be found at [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74587/project-euler-3-in-java/74600#74600).

I'd appreciate any comments on rewriting `maxPrimeFact` as it seems unwieldy to me.

Comment: cf. [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/68684/9064) with a pseudocode which should be easy enough to turn into a valid Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to terminate the list of candidate factors.  Haskell, being a lazy language, deals with infinite lists just fine.

In Haskell, it is common to use pattern matching instead of `if … then … else`.

There is not much advantage to having your `go` helper take an `Integer (Integer, Integer)` rather than three `Integer`s.

You are repeating the `isDiv` test in `fullyDiv` and `go`.  Instead of a `fullyDiv` function, you can just fold the retry logic into `go` itself.

The names `x`, `y`, and `o` are hard to follow.  I suggest `maxPrime` instead of `x`, and `w` instead of `y` (the mnemonic being the first character of `wheel`).

```
isDiv :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
n `isDiv` k = n `mod` k == 0

maxPrimeFact :: Integer -> Integer
maxPrimeFact n = go n 1 (2 : [3, 5..])
  where
    go 1 maxPrime _ = maxPrime
    go n maxPrime wheel@(w:ws)
      | n `isDiv` w = go (n `div` w) w wheel
      | otherwise   = go n maxPrime ws
```

But you should be able to rewrite it further by taking advantage of `divMod`.

```
maxPrimeFact :: Integer -> Integer
maxPrimeFact n
  | n < 2     = error ("Invalid n=" ++ (show n))
  | otherwise = go n 1 wheel
  where
    wheel = 2 : [3, 5..]
    go 1 largestPrimeFactor _ = largestPrimeFactor
    go n largestPrimeFactor (w:ws)
      | n `isDiv` w = go (n `div` w) w (w:ws)
      | otherwise   = go n largestPrimeFactor ws
```

Comment: It appears that the `go` function you wrote would iterate all the way till the maximum prime. The reason why I wrote the function as such was to reduce the search space (refer to my answer which I referred above). Otherwise, thanks for the excellent suggestions!

Comment: The program completes in 0.02 sec. I wouldn't bother with premature optimization.

Comment: I'm actually using this program in https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges where it errors out in the last case: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler003/submissions/code/2560702.

Comment: I made the change and it passes all tests: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler003/submissions/code/2560723. Anyways, thanks for the new `maxPrimeFact` function; I'll mark your answer as accepted.