# Very slow Project Euler Q3 (largest prime factor of a large number)

Tags: javascript, performance, programming-challenge, primes

My code returns the correct answer for the example (highest prime of  13195 is 29), but when I test against the number in the question my code basically is too slow for my liking.

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

Is there anything obviously wrong with my logic or any ways to improve?

```
(function(){

var theNumber = 600851475143; // testing this number, sub in 13195 to verify 

var getHighestPrimeFactor = function(number){
    var upto = (number / 2) % 2 == 0 ? (number/2) : Math.floor(number/2);
    var factors = [];

    for(var i = upto; i > 1; i--){
        if(number % i == 0){
            factors.push(i);
            if(isPrimeFactor(i) == true){
                console.log("high prime = " + i);
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
} // end getHighestPrimeFactor

var isPrimeFactor = function(number){
    var upto = number / 2;
    var isItPrime = true;
    for(var i = 2; i < upto; i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            isItPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isItPrime;
} // end isPrimeFactor

var x = getHighestPrimeFactor(theNumber);
console.log(x);

})();
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar questions [have been asked before](/a/48185/9357).  You are using the "test the largest candidate factors first" strategy, which does not scale well at all.  You should test the smallest candidate factors first.

Comment: So the 3rd door, testing the smallest candidate factors, I begin by dividing n (the number we're checking the highest prime factor for) by 'small' prime factors, i.e. 2-3-5-7-11-19- until the prime factor dividing n gives us an int, take that number and repeat until I basically recursively call the highest prime on itself?

Comment: Updated.. I think it's all there, but still pretty slow. Been running for about 5 minutes now, even as a node.js file

Comment: Disregard, found what I was missing appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

So the here's the code in JS if anyone wants to see it in action, just required following 200_success's advice and another answer seen here

[Project Euler #3 - largest prime factor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46906/project-euler-3-largest-prime-factor/48185#48185)

That answer led the the improved algorithm below, especially #3 that is listed.

Code here:

```
(function(){

var n = 600851475143; // testing this number
//var n = 13195; // sub in, largest prime factor is 29
var primeFactors = [];


var findHighestPrime = function(number){
    var bound = Math.floor(number/2); 

    for(var i = 2; i < bound; i+=2 ){
        if(number % i == 0){ // it's a factor, is it prime though? 
            if(isPrimeFactor(i) == true){
                primeFactors.push(i);
                if(number/i == 1){ // stop here, it's the highest prime factor
                    break;
                } else {
                    number = number / i; // "recursively" check the newest number
                }                   
            }
        }
        i = (i%2==0) ? i-= 1 : i; // added this in for speeding up the algorithm a little.
    }
}

var isPrimeFactor = function(number){
    var upto = number / 2; // only need to measure up to half of the number
    var isItPrime = true;
    for(var i = 2; i < upto; i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            isItPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isItPrime;
} // end isPrimeFactor

findHighestPrime(n);
console.log(primeFactors[primeFactors.length-1]);

})();
```

Comment: Give some thought to why you are calling `isPrimeFactor(i)`.

Comment: @200_success hmm not exactly sure if I understand why I wouldn't call that, is it not necessary? It's necessary (as far as I understand) to make sure the factor of the number isn't just a factor-- but obviously a prime factor

Comment: If you have already tried all smaller candidate factors, then …?

Comment: @200_success oh think I see where you're leading me. so basically, push the smaller factors when a larger one is found into an array (or something) and then check only ones larger than that? is that where you are going with this?

Comment: It can be even simpler than that.

Comment: @200_success may just because it's Friday, and it's been a long week, however-- I'm stumped.. how can it be simpler than that?

Comment: You don't need to test `isPrime()` for the same reason that you don't need to try even factors greater than 2.